# Cannot import category encoder due to module error

Tags: encoding, jupyter-notebook, data-science

PLEASE HELP!!

Cannot import category_encoder using Jupyter Notebook [This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnL6A.png)

It is installed using `conda install -c conda-forge category_encoders`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give error messages by text (not image).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.